# Ajax call not get the real value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twig

I have the following .html code :

```
{% for item in pager.recordList %}
  <td>
    <a id="log_ig" class="log_ig" href="{{ 'my_route'|url_route }}">{{ item.statut }}</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ item.id }}" id="ig_hidden">
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```

And the jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function() {
        $('.log_ig').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ 'my_route'|url_route }}',
                data: {
                    id_ig: $('#ig_hidden').val()
                },
                success :  function(data){
                    $.nmData(data);
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            })
        });
        });
    });
```

The problem is that my `id_ig` in the request have every time the first value from array. So, if I have an array with `item.id [1..10]` my `$('#ig_hidden').val()` return the first value. I don't understand where is my problem. Can you help me please ?

Comment: ID values must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bad concepts in your code.

```
{% for item in pager.recordList %}
  <td>
    <a id="log_ig" class="log_ig" href="{{ 'my_route'|url_route }}">{{ item.statut }}</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ item.id }}" name="ig_hidden">
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Change id to name on the input. Id should be unique.

I'm guessing that you have this code inside a `<form></form>`

You should serialize and send that data on the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function() {
        $('.log_ig').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ 'my_route'|url_route }}',
                data: $('#some-form').serialize(),
                success :  function(data){
                    $.nmData(data);
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            })
        });
        });
    });
```

And this way you will send all data that is in the form!